# How to calculate the pH of a solution given the concentration and pKa's of solutes?

Tags: ph

For example, if I have a solution of 50mM acetlycholine (pKa = 4.5), how would I go about calculating the pH of the solution?

Thanks

Comment: You wouldn't. In situations like this, you would typically have some other solutes at much greater concentrations, and it is _them_ that will ultimately define the resulting pH. Otherwise, go for the [Ostwald’s dilution law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_dilution).

Comment: A pKa of 4.5 would be typical for a carboxylic acid group, but I don't see any functional groups that look like it (there is a quaternary amine and an ester group, neither one have acid/base chemistry in water). What else is in the solution, and what is the solvent?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming in your example that there is only one solute. If you have more than one then ionisation is mutually suppressed and things are a bit more complicated.

A useful expression that you can derive from an ICE table for a weak acid is:

$\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\rm pH=\dfrac{1}{2}[pK_a-\log{c}]$

Where c is the concentration of the acid which we assume to be just about equal to the equilibrium concentration.

This is reasonable for $\rm pK_a$ values between 4 and 10.

Putting in the numbers:

$\rm pH=\dfrac{1}{2}[4.5-(-1.3)]$

$\rm \underline{pH=2.9}$

Acetylcholine has a quaternary nitrogen so I can only assume that, given that the $\rm pK_a$ value is correct, the deprotonisation occurs at a different site on the molecule.

Comment: How did you get log(0.05) = -0.7?

Comment: Oops ! Sorry about that. Should be -1.3. Have corrected answer.